# How do you extend static properties in ES Next?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

Sometimes (albeit rarely) you need to extend, rather than overwrite parent static properties, such as (the very lame) example below:

```
class Person {
    static coreStats = {
        role: "slacker",
        weapon: null,
        speed: 4,
        vechicle: "roller blades",
    };
}

class Ninja extends Person {
    static coreStats = {
        role: "silent assassin",
        weapon: "katana",
        speed: 99,
    };
}

console.log(Ninja.coreStats); // But vechicle is no more
```

How does one extend the static properties in a child class without clobbering the parent properties?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are static properties (not static methods), part of ES6? Or is there a TC39 proposal for this somewhere?

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties

Comment: Rolled back the edit because I was specifically asking about ES2015. If its not available in 2015, happy for the answer to be "not possible in es2015"

Comment: Well, then: Not possible in ES 2015, because it has no support for class properties in the first place. So if you are "specifically asking about ES2015"  I really wonder how the question came into existence :)

Comment: @zeroflagL Gotcha - I thought statics were part of ES6/ES2015 based on reading this article: http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html but I must be off because that is only talking about static methods

Comment: @nils Based on convo with zeroflagL I rolled back my roll back - my bad on the confusion there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
class Person {
    static coreStats = {
        role: "slacker",
        weapon: null,
        speed: 4,
        vechicle: "roller blades",
    };
}

class Ninja extends Person {
    static coreStats = Object.assign({}, Person.coreStats, {
        role: "silent assassin",
        weapon: "katana",
        speed: 99
    });
}
console.log(Ninja.coreStats);
```

This will merge `coreStats` and override `Person.coreStats` with `Ninja.coreStats` in case of duplications

Comment: In Ninja : `static coreStats = Object.assign({}, Person.coreStats, {
        role: "silent assassin",
        weapon: "katana",
        speed: 99
    });` ?

Comment: Edited answer according to @Apolo suggestion. It looks even cleaner now.

Comment: This isn't good, what's happen when you do `class Foo extends Person` ??

Comment: @Hitmands I'm not sure I understand. I am pretty sure Dmittriy is right with the above answer?

Comment: @Hitmands `Foo.coreStats === Person.coreStats`? What's the problem there?